# upload image at opencard

Tags: opencart, permission-denied, image-upload

move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phptOjhzD' to '/var/www/html/garageluxe/upload/image/catalog/demo/manufacturer/GLB6147_1.jpg' in /var/www/html/garageluxe/upload/admin/controller/common/filemanager.php on line 277

**The error appeard at error log**

Answer (score 0):

1- check image folder and sub folders permission - for test set permission to 777
2- check DIR_IMAGE path in config.php file
3- check tmp folder - remove old data into tmp folder